# Forcing covariates to always be part of a Lasso model

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, model-selection, lasso, regularization

I want to use a Lasso to predict outcomes for different policy scenarios. At the optimal degree of regularization obtained by cross-validation, one important variable in whose impact I'm interested in is not kept in the model. Is there a (statistically valid) way to include a set of variables that always shall be part of the model? Both adding those variables after regularizing and determining the degree of regularization "manually" such that all the desired variables still are included don't seem theoretically okay to me. I know that my approach to force some variables to stay in the model isn't the nicest, but is it still justifyable from a statistical point of view?

Answer (score 1):

Lasso by default adds a regularization penalty for all the parameters, but nothing prohibits you from penalizing only some of the parameters. Running lasso and "adding back" the zeroed-out parameters to retrain the model with them is not the best idea, because the model found by the lasso algorithm was the most optimal model without them. If you add them back, it's not the optimal model anymore, the algorithm might have found a completely different solution when they were present.

You said that you are interested in the impact of one of the variables that lasso dropped. So are you doing prediction or inference? Lasso produces biased estimates, so if you are interested in interpreting the results, it is not the best algorithm. Why would you use lasso in this case at all?

Comment: I want to make predictions on how outcomes change when some of the covariates change. As there are many covariates, I want to regularize and thus use a Lasso. So, while the aim is not to interpret the results, I still to keep key variables which, from a theoretical point of view, are "sure" to have an effect on the outcome. Do you say it is generally not valid to use the Lasso in such a case? And how could one technically achieve not to penalize a subset of the covariates?

Comment: @Mattis to penalize a subset of parameters, you need to define a cost function that adds penalty only for some of the parameters. This likely means that you cannot use any of the out-of-the-box software for the lasso, at least I don't recall that any allows for that.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'm only aware of the Stata funcion which allows for that but want to avoid to use it. And even if it's not the essential part of the question: Would you say that using the Lasso for my task nevertheless is valid?

Comment: @Mattis as said it looks like you are interested in inference rather than prediction and lasso will give you biased results. Maybe you should use a Bayesian regression with different priors for the parameters instead? It is hard to comment without in-depth knowledge of your data and the problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I understand, I've posted a follow-up question giving details [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574640/policy-evaluation-using-machine-learning-techniques-when-interested-in-impact-of)